# I have a question regarding the ANY operator in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When I use !ANY in this query, why am I getting 2200, 2259.99, 2269.99 along with the rest? Isn't this query supposed to exclude these three values' product_name and list_price?

```
SELECT product_name, list_price
FROM products
WHERE list_price != ANY(
        2200, 2259.99, 2269.99
    ) AND category_id = 1
ORDER BY list_price DESC;
```

This gets returned:

```
-------------------------------------------
PRODUCT_NAME                   |LIST_PRICE|
-------------------------------------------
INTEL XEON E5-2699 V3(OEM/TRAY)|3410.46   |
INTEL XEON E5-2697 V3          |2774.98   |
INTEL XEON E5-2699 V3(OEM/TRAY)|2660.72   |
INTEL XEON E5-2697 V4          |2554.99   |
INTEL XEON E5-2685 V3(OEM/TRAY)|2501.69   |
INTEL XEON E5-2695 V3(OEM/TRAY)|2431.95   |
INTEL XEON E5-2697 V2          |2377.09   |
INTEL XEON E5-2695 V4          |2269.99   |
INTEL XEON E5-2695 V2          |2259.99   |
INTEL XEON E5-2695 V2(OEM/TRAY)|2200      |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This example is taken from [the OracleTutorial site](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-any/)

Comment: yes i was learning from that website and i did not understand this part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list_price != ANY(2200, 2259.99, 2269.99)` translates to

```
   list_price <> 2200
or list_price <> 2259.99 
or list_price <> 2269.99
```

You need `!= ALL` or simply `NOT IN` which translates to

```
    list_price <> 2200
and list_price <> 2259.99 
and list_price <> 2269.99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT product_name, list_price
    FROM products p1
    WHERE  NOT ( p1.list_price = ANY ( Select  p2.list_price from products p2 where list_price 
    IN(2200, 2259.99, 2269.99) and AND category_id = 1 ))
    ORDER BY p1.list_price DESC;
```

Inner query returns IN(2200, 2259.99, 2269.99) three rows but outer query select all price except these three because we use NOT in where clause.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.